# Before/After slider HTML5 starting position

Tags: javascript, css, html

I've recently came across [this before/after slider](https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/EIKzk) on codepen.io.

But I have a question: how can I change the position where the slider starts. The slider starts int he middle, and I don't see where in this code that is set:

```
function trackLocation(e) {
  var rect = videoContainer.getBoundingClientRect(),
      position = ((e.pageX - rect.left) / videoContainer.offsetWidth)*100;
  if (position <= 100) { 
    videoClipper.style.width = position+"%";
    clippedVideo.style.width = ((100/position)*100)+"%";
    clippedVideo.style.zIndex = 3;
    }
}
var videoContainer = document.getElementById("video-compare-container"),
videoClipper = document.getElementById("video-clipper"),
clippedVideo = videoClipper.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
videoContainer.addEventListener( "mousemove", trackLocation, false); 
videoContainer.addEventListener("touchstart",trackLocation,false);
videoContainer.addEventListener("touchmove",trackLocation,false);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), make sure you read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and updated your question with more information.

Comment: Minor edits for legibility.

Answer (score 1):

on the bottom of the css

```
#video-clipper video {
  width: 450%;
  postion: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  }
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jwMwXB

Comment: Yeah that one i found, but if i adjust the width it still starts in the middle. 
It needs to start all the way on the left.

Comment: Oke it kinda buggy when u refresh the page, but it works now thanks! Is there maybe a way so after delay of 2sec or so it does slide to the middle?